# Variable parameter class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, variadic-functions

The following code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fun(new Integer(1));
    }
    static void fun(Object ... a) {
        System.out.println(a.getClass());
    }
```

gives the output :-

```
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

What class is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `Object[]` array.

To get the runtime type information:

```
a.getClass().isArray() -> true
a.getClass().getComponentType().getName() -> java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 6):

according to [the JVM specifications](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#14757) it is simply an **array of java.lang.Object**:

- **[** means a monodimensional array
- **LfullyQualifiedName;** means a class, L; is just syntax

Comment: it is used only as delimiter, no special meaning; did you read the specifications?

Answer (score 1):

This is how [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) (methods with a variable number of arguments) work in Java - the varargs argument will look like an array inside the method.